# Can we use VC redist 2015 instead of VC2012 and VC2013?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, vcredist

I was using VC2012 and VC2013. I added one DLL which requires VC2015. Then I removed VC2012 and VC2013 and just used single VC2015. But after this application crashes randomly.

Can we use VC redist 2015 instead of VC2012 and VC2013? and is VC2015 backward compatible?

Comment: The redist is not backward compatible, the DLL names are not even the same.  And object layouts often change between major versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VC redist is dont follow backward compatibility.. only 2017 is follow only for 2015.. so need to intall all(11,12,13,15) and you can install 2017 insteed of 2015